# Migrate from Webpack to Vite: how resolve path alias and get imports to work

Tags: reactjs, typescript, alias, vite

I am migrating my project from Webpack to Vite `"vite": "^4.3.9",`.

After `npm start` I get this error:

> Error: The following dependencies are imported but could not be
> resolved:

In my React Typescript files I imported like this:

```
import { cacheOpts, typeDefs } from 'app/graphql/cache';
```

What do I have to do to be able te keep all imports as is?

In `tsconfig.json` I have:

```
"baseUrl": "./src",
"paths": {
      "*": ["shared/*", "client/*", "server/*", "*"]
    },
```

I saw in `vite.config.ts` I can add `path.resolve`:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
      src: path.resolve('src/'),
    },
  }
```

How do I get my imports to work?

Answer (score 2):

use this package it's perfect and it resolved the issue 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-tsconfig-paths
after installing, go edit your `vite.config.ts`:

```html
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), tsconfigPaths()]
})
```

Comment: Thank you for answering this question. You might want to give some more objective details ("it's perfect and it resolved the issue*" is subjective and not much informative).

Answer (score 1):

A common technique is to use the `resolve` section in `vite.config.ts` to alias the '@' symbol as the source directory root so you don't need to have relative paths. ie.

```
import path from 'path';
...
export default defineConfig({
...
    resolve: {
        alias: { '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') },
    },
})
```

And in `tsconfig.json`, dispense with `baseUrl` but use

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "paths": { "@/*": ["./src/*"] },
        ...
    }
    "include": ["src"],
    ...
}
```

Then, assuming your `app` folder is a child of your `src` folder the import becomes

```
import { cacheOpts, typeDefs } from '@/app/graphql/cache';
```

If you're happy to use relative paths then dispense with the `resolve... alias` in `vite.config.ts`, and use this in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  ...
}
```